# how to extract multiple column data in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a macro which extracts data from certain columns from another file. I have encountered an error message of

> Type mismatch

at line `Set row = Columns("O,Q,W")` I know this is not correct and I have tried with Union also but that is also not working.

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim row1 As Integer
Dim hello As Range
Dim hello1 As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))

        With wkbSourceBook.Worksheets(1)
            lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        For i = 4 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
                Set row = Columns("O,Q,W")
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then


            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            row.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntirdoeColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
            '~~> Change Sheet2 to relevant sheet name
        End If
        End With


    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Set MyRange = Union(Columns(1), Columns(4))
```

will catch several columns at once

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, it does work, but it prompts me that ` it can't do that to a merged cell`, so I'm wondering how to I copy these columns data to another worksheet properly.

Comment: that's because some cell in the column you are trying to capture is merged, run through the columns and unmerge what you can then it should work

Comment: then just Myrange.copy destination:= targetsheet.range("A1")

Comment: I have checked that there's no merged cells, but my code is like `hello.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")`

Comment: Maybe the header of data is a merged cell or on some other cells far down like A1000, select manually each of the columns one at a time and check the "merge/unmerge button" if its yellow then something is merged. Your instruction is ok works same as mine. If that doesn't help then I am sorry I cant think of solution atm

Comment: Thank you for your precious advice:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Columns()` like that. Also avoid the use of `Row` as a variable. It is a reserved word.

Change it to

```
Set rw= .Range("O:O,Q:Q,W:W")
```

or like what @KKowalczyk suggested

```
Set rw = Union(.Columns(15), .Columns(17), .Columns(23))
```

Forgot to mention that please also qualify your cells object. Notice the dots before them? If you don't then they will address the `Activesheet` which may or may not be the sheet that you actually think it is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, it does work, but it prompts me that `it can't do that to a merged cell`, so I'm wondering how to I copy these columns data to another worksheet properly.

Comment: @KKowalczyk has already suggested on how to copy that. You can unmerge the cells and then copy?

Comment: But unfortunately I could not find any merged cells in that worksheet

Comment: How are you checking?

Comment: I think I find the problem already, thx. And if you don't mind, do you think `Set destination = Sheets(2).Union(.Columns(8), .Columns(10), .Columns(12), .Columns(13))` is correct?

Comment: No. put `Sheets(2)` before every dot in that line :)

Comment: `Set destination = Sheets(2).Union(Sheets(2).Columns(8), Sheets(2).Columns(10), Sheets(2).Columns(12), Sheets(2).Columns(13))` causes an error message of `object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: My apologies. forgot to mention that you need to remove it before the union. Use this `Set Destination = Union(Sheets(2).Columns(8), Sheets(2).Columns(10), Sheets(2).Columns(12), Sheets(2).Columns(13))`

Comment: Thank you for your help, may I ask for one more thing? Since I have the cells `Set rw = Union(.Columns(3), .Columns(15), .Columns(17), .Columns(23))` to copy and then paste at `Set destination = Union(Sheets(2).Columns(8), Sheets(2).Columns(10), Sheets(2).Columns(12), Sheets(2).Columns(13))` Why `rw.Copy destination` is not working? The error message says `That command cannot be used on multiple selections`

Comment: I am slightly confused. Where do you want to copy from and to where?

Comment: I want to copy those cells (column 3&15&17&23) to the columns(column 8&10&12&13)

Comment: You can't do that. You will have to individually copy them... 3-->8 then 15-->10 and so on.